# .select() works with first click , not on second click.

Tags: javascript

i m using a simple js method to select all text

```
onmouseup="(this).select();
```

it is working fine on first click but when i click it second time its not working

here is my code part:

```
<TEXTAREA type="text" onmouseup="(this).select();"  value="click me to autoselect" id="textBox" spellcheck="false" readonly ></TEXTAREA>
```

> i mean that it is only working on first,third,fifth ..... click
>
> not on second,fourth,sixth.... click //sometimes

here is a jsfiddle example you can try here what want to tell you.
http://jsfiddle.net/wjb3me3k/

> //working on chrome

please answer in javascript , im not familiar with jquery. thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default browser behavior when you click on a text input is to position the cursor where you clicked. As a result of that, the selection is undone.

Replace

```
(this).select();
```

with

```
(this).select(); return false;
```

Returning `false` from a handler suppresses the browser's default behavior.

Comment: Pretty much, but "all browsers" is a very complicated thing to talk about. Also, the `select` method will *not* work in all browsers. This is why you should use a library (such as jQuery) unless you're an expert.